# Modify the delimiter of an external table with HiveQL

Tags: database, hadoop, hdfs, hiveql

I'm taking a CSV file from HDFS and transferring it to my External Table in hive.

But my CSV file has the delimiter " ; " and in my second column, I have " ; " along with the information.

You can see in the image below:

[image]

[image]

Can you guide me what I should do? Are there any Hive properties that allow me to do this or any other solution?

Comment: Please show your current Hive table definition

Comment: @OneCricketeer, To explain better: I have a CSV file that I transfer via put into an EXTERNAL TABLE in Hive, but the delimiter of this CSV is " ; ", and the second column has some information with " ; ".

If I put the ROW FORMAT TEXT FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' it will recognize " ; " as a new column, and that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: My CSV table looks like this, but with a lot of other information and " ; " in the second column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ibd.png

Comment: When transferring my CSV to the table in Hive, I want to leave it that way, you know? Ignoring the " ; " in the second column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfT5m.png

Comment: Those images are the exact same as your post, and as answered, the only way to get what you want is to quote the middle column so the semi-colon doesnt split the values

Comment: Do I do this on table creation? I'm doing it this way:     CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bd.table(category STRING COMMENT 'aaa', type STRING COMMENT 'bbb', country STRING COMMENT 'ccc') COMMENT 'ddd'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

Comment: How can I do what you said in the second column? thanks for your help @OneCricketeer

Comment: You need to actually edit the file. This isn't something you can solve with anything from Hive

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ROW FORMAT TEXT FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'` will split it apart

If you want the `(OS)` value to be part of the second column, you need to quote that column. e.g. `A;"Mozilla//5.0;(Linux)";BR`. In other words, change how the file is written/stored *outside of Hive*

If you cannot modify the file, you can make your queries simply concatenate those two columns, e.g. `SELECT CONCAT(user_agent, ';',  os) FROM data;`